# Shiro permissions in Grails Bootstrap

Tags: grails, shiro, bootstrapping

I create some permissions for some controllers and actions in grails bootstrap file for registered users, but every time when i create a new controller or a new action I must delete the table to take changes. but what i can do when I deploy an app in prod and after some time I add some actions and permissions for that action in the app? how I can give permissions to the new actions for registered users without deleting any table or db? manualy add them or what? in mysql a can't manually edit permissions table.

Answer (score 0):

Two step solution:

- assign roles to your users, not permissions.
- rebuild the roles with each restart of your app. It's easy to create some code in your bootstrap which first removes all roles and then creates the right roles with the right permissio.s with each restart.

At least, that's how I handle this problem...